# Jest React Enzyme test case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

```
export default class StudentGrid extends Component {
  static handleScroll() {
    const studentTableHeader = document.getElementById('student-table-header');
    const studentTable = document.getElementById('student-table');
    const scrolldiv = document.getElementsByClassName('main')[0].scrollTop; // From DOM
    const sticky = studentTableHeader.offsetTop;
    if (scrolldiv >= sticky) {
      studentTableHeader.classList.add('studentList__sticky');
      studentTable.classList.add('studentList__managetop');
    } else {
      studentTableHeader.classList.remove('studentList__sticky');
      studentTable.classList.remove('studentList__managetop');
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', StudentGrid.handleScroll, true);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', StudentGrid.handleScroll, true);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="pe-container-fill">
        <div className="responsive-table">
          <div className="table" id="student-table">
            <div
              className="table-row table__header"
              id="student-table-header"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Help me writing test cases (Using Jest and Enzyme)
1. Simulate scroll, need to call handleScroll function check
2. Need to check class 'studentList__sticky' and 'studentList__managetop' present or not.

Answer (score -1):

You can look on this page [airbnb.io - enzyme / jest](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/jest.html).
You will have to learn about the shallow, full dom and static rendering. This will be very usefull for your comprehension about the testing process of Jest and Enzyme.

You can look [hackernoon.com - enzyme / jest](https://hackernoon.com/testing-react-components-with-jest-and-enzyme-41d592c174f).
This will show and explain some test case.